# VBA code to extract Excel files from Multiple zip files

Tags: excel, vba

How can I use a VBA code to extract Excel files from multiple zip files.

My folder has multiple zip files. Those zip files contain Excel files `.xls`. How can I build a VBA code for this and save all Excel files to a single folder?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
     Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
     Dim fldr As Folder
     Dim file1 As File

     Dim objApp As Object
     Set objApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
     objApp.Namespace(Destinationfolder &"\").CopyHere (objApp.Namespace(Zippedfilepath).Items)
     Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(Destinationfolder)

     For Each file1 In fldr.Files
         If file1.Type <> "Microsoft Excel Worksheet" Then
            file1.Delete
         End If
    Next
```

Comment: Hi, The link will only extract the zip files but I need only the excel files to be extracted from multiple zip files.